# Why is terminal telling me that my .rar file is not a RAR archive?

Tags: file-format, rar

The file was downloaded online am I am trying to get a PS2 emulator working on my computer for fun. All I need to do now is learn how to open this rar file.

File output of:

```
superpajamarama@:~$ file "/home/superpajamarama/Desktop/PS2 Games/Futurama.rar"
/home/superpajamarama/Desktop/PS2 Games/Futurama.rar: empty
```

This is what the terminal says when trying to unrar:

```
superpajamarama:~$ unrar x /home/superpajamarama/Desktop/PS2 Games/Futurama.rar

UNRAR 5.00 beta 8 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2013 Alexander Roshal

/home/superpajamarama/Desktop/PS2 Games/Futurama.rar is not RAR archive
No files to extract
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the output of `file "/home/superpajamarama/Desktop/PS2 Games/Futurama.rar"`

Comment: 3 possible reasons: 1. the file is not compatible with rar 5.00 2. it is not a complete download. 3. the file is password protected

Comment: @terdon do you mean type that into the terminal?

Comment: @Superpajamarama Yes, type it into terminal and add the output in your question

Comment: Yes, `file` is a command, just like `unrar` is. It is a program that gives you information about a file. In this case, it will give us a hint about what `Futurama.rar` actually is and whether it is indeed a rar archive.

Comment: I wonder, why not install the 7z-rar module and run 7z for it. It handles a lot of RAR issues pretty good.

Comment: @Superpajamarama you are missing a " at the end in your command! that's why it is garbled.

Comment: The command was supposed to be all on a single line, like this (extra space added to force a line break): `file "/home/superpajamarama/Desktop/PS2 Games/Futurama.rar"`

Comment: @terdon :Thanks for editing the question for me :P. I will copy your line and give it a go.

Comment: @terdon : thank you for that haha. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your file is empty. Probably an unfinished download or just the wrong file altogether. You will need to go back to wherever you got it from and try to download it again.

In future, remember that you can always use the `file` command to determine the file type of a file. In this particular case, you would also have been able to see that its empty by running

```
ls -lh  "/home/superpajamarama/Desktop/PS2 Games/Futurama.rar"
```

which would have shown an 0 byte sized file.

Answer (score 4):

Actually two things comes to my mind:

Either archive is corrupted, it can be checked

> unrar t file.rar

or rar is password protected

> unrar e -pYOURPASS file.rar