# Unable to extract extracting .rar file?

Tags: rar

I have installed unrar as:

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
```

I have a "html.rar" file.Now i am trying to extract using command :

```
unrar x html.rar
```

But it shows an error as given below:

```
html.rar is not RAR archive
No files to extract
```

How to overcome from such problem ?

Comment: Okay, what does show the `file html.rar`?

Comment: "html.rar is not RAR archive" What is it and where did you get it ? unrar is working fine for me.

Comment: when i use to unpack html.rar by using unrar x html.rar ,it shows error as :

Comment: Either archive is corrupted, it can be checked `unrar t file.rar`  
or rar is password protected  `unrar e -pYOURPASS file.rar`

Comment: unrar x html.rar is not working and its not password protected..

Comment: @RajenderRajan *show the output of `file html.rar`*

Comment: @RajenderRajan can you post the out put of  `unrar t html.rar`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is terminal telling me that my .rar file is not a RAR archive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/464104/why-is-terminal-telling-me-that-my-rar-file-is-not-a-rar-archive)

Comment: Its working fine i reinstalled unrar. Thanks eveyone !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check the *.rar with **file** command to determine the type of file.

```
file html.rar
```

Make sure your file is properly downloaded, sometimes it may be unfinished download.

Then check the size of the file by executing

```
ls -lh
```

If it is an empty file then redownload it. Or check with

```
unrar t html.rar
```

-t : Test archive files

Hope it helps.

Comment: running a test showed "All OK"... when extracting the top of the log said "permission denied" it was easy to miss.

Comment: permission denied was my issue too.